vector-valued reproducing kernel Hilbert space
I'm studying vector-valued RKHS in classification context. While I'm finding consistent literature about RKHS for real-valued functions I'm stumbling upon seemingly different definitions for vector-valued RKHS.
Let $\mathcal{H}$ the considered Hilbert space of functions $f:\mathcal{X}\mapsto\mathcal{Y}$.
For instance, in Carmeli & al., "Vector valued reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces and universality", they define them as: $\forall x\in\mathcal{X}$ the linear forms $\forall f\in \mathcal{H},L_x(f)=f(x)$ are continuous.
But in Micchelli, "On Learning Vector-Valued Functions", it's $\forall x\in\mathcal{X},\forall y\in\mathcal{Y}$ the linear forms such that $\forall f\in \mathcal{H},L_{x;y}(f)=<y,f(x)>_\mathcal{Y}$ are continuous.
Are these definitions equivalent? Why?

Afterthought:

The second seem to imply the first one by using a special $y$ and going back to the definition of continuity.
The first one seem to imply the second one by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.


The first definition is simply an extension of the definition for the scalar-valued case, which states that the evaluation functional is bounded for RKHS's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space). Your afterthoughts also seem correct to me, so that one definition implies the other.
